# Deployed Meteor app to Heroku not working

Tags: meteor, heroku

I have deployed an app to Heroku using this tutorial: https://medium.com/@leonardykris/how-to-run-a-meteor-js-application-on-heroku-in-10-steps-7aceb12de234

I've even just created a new app with `meteor create herokutest`, created a new heroku app called ludotestone, and pushed it to Heroku Git, but still its not working.

When I run `heroku logs --tail` I get the following result:

```
2017-02-22T15:56:07.680626+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T15:56:07.529897+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T15:56:07.645071+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T15:56:07.645071+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T15:56:07.752423+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T15:56:07.529897+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T15:56:29.993806+00:00 app[api]: Attach MONGODB (@ref:mongolab-silhouetted-71457) by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T15:56:29.993806+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T15:56:30.133334+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T15:57:59.468311+00:00 app[api]: Set MONGO_URL config vars by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T15:57:59.468311+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T15:57:59.651147+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T15:58:32.383523+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=ludotestone.herokuapp.com request_id=ef4376e2-218a-44ee-89ee-a8c762c23a11 fwd="37.235.112.81" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2017-02-22T15:58:32.907631+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ludotestone.herokuapp.com request_id=1b246c81-49bd-450d-8e83-7bd83e095504 fwd="37.235.112.81" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2017-02-22T15:58:50.239561+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T15:58:50.239561+00:00 app[api]: Set ROOT_URL config vars by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T15:58:50.375276+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T15:59:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T16:07:15.247743+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T16:07:15.205972+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 7970970 by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T16:07:15.205972+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T16:07:15.586286+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user dev@friendsagency.com
2017-02-22T15:59:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-02-22T16:07:43.758842+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node build/bundle/main.js`
2017-02-22T16:07:46.734182+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2017-02-22T16:07:46.620143+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-22T16:07:46.621194+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw new assert.AssertionError({
2017-02-22T16:07:46.620605+00:00 app[web.1]: assert.js:93
2017-02-22T16:07:46.621196+00:00 app[web.1]:         ^
2017-02-22T16:07:46.623579+00:00 app[web.1]: AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"
2017-02-22T16:07:46.623582+00:00 app[web.1]:     at wrapPathFunction (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10)
2017-02-22T16:07:46.623583+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)
2017-02-22T16:07:46.623583+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2017-02-22T16:07:46.623585+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2017-02-22T16:07:46.623585+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2017-02-22T16:07:46.623586+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2017-02-22T16:07:46.623586+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2017-02-22T16:07:46.623587+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2017-02-22T16:07:46.623587+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
2017-02-22T16:07:46.623588+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2017-02-22T16:07:46.763859+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-02-22T16:07:46.764493+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-02-22T16:08:12.517015+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node build/bundle/main.js`
2017-02-22T16:08:14.723827+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-22T16:08:14.724103+00:00 app[web.1]: assert.js:93
2017-02-22T16:08:14.724315+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw new assert.AssertionError({
2017-02-22T16:08:14.724317+00:00 app[web.1]:         ^
2017-02-22T16:08:14.725795+00:00 app[web.1]: AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"
2017-02-22T16:08:14.725796+00:00 app[web.1]:     at wrapPathFunction (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10)
2017-02-22T16:08:14.725797+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)
2017-02-22T16:08:14.725798+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2017-02-22T16:08:14.725798+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2017-02-22T16:08:14.725799+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2017-02-22T16:08:14.725799+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2017-02-22T16:08:14.725800+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2017-02-22T16:08:14.725800+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2017-02-22T16:08:14.725800+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/build/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
2017-02-22T16:08:14.725801+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2017-02-22T16:08:14.849873+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-02-22T16:08:14.831165+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2017-02-22T16:20:15.789306+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ludotestone.herokuapp.com request_id=4e8276da-dda8-4dcc-b4eb-9a480acb00d3 fwd="37.235.112.81" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-02-22T16:20:17.692344+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ludotestone.herokuapp.com request_id=ecf0bbfe-a03c-477d-9af1-69d27c9ec548 fwd="37.235.112.81" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I have no idea what's going on, and how to fix this.

Comment: Hello, did you setup a database connection such as the mLab addon?

Comment: I also recommend this tutorial https://medium.com/@gge/deploy-a-meteor-1-3-application-to-heroku-cda1f68ca20a?source=linkShare-c7dc78f050b1-1487785105

Comment: I have seen that tutorial, but thought it was the same as this one I used.. Yours worked! Thanks sir